# Pass URL in Custom Action Data

Tags: c#, asp.net, wix

I have created a VS 2008 web setup project with a dialog so that I can modify the web.config file at install. The setup worked as expected. However, I can not seem to accept a URL for a property value via custom data. I know directories are escaped with "\", is there any similar escaping or tricks for a URL.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for the

['HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode'](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w.aspx)

method?

Hope this helps,